# Python Atomic Clock Webscraping

Tags: python

I'm trying to simply get the atomic time from the website
https://www.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/eng/services/time/web_clock.html using python. I know there are ways to do this in python without webscraping, this is just to get some practice with webscraping. I've come up with this so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://www.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/eng/services/time/web_clock.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
for i in range(len(soup.find_all('p'))):
    print(str(i) + soup.find_all('p')[i].get_text())
```

This doesn't show any text that has the time, it shows a bunch of text from other paragraphs and some blank lines, but no time. I'm not sure what the problem is as I believe the time is being stored in the paragraph tag. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What *is* the actual problem?

Comment: sorry I accidentally deleted it, the problem is that when it outputs the text, the time is never printed. I'm not sure why, there is a big portion of output that is just blank, and more that is the text in other paragraph tags, but no time

Comment: in python you can use `for i, item in enumerate(soup.find_all('p')): print(i, item.get_text() )`

Comment: it seems this page use JavaScript to display time, but requests+BS can't run JavaScript. You may need `Selenium` to control web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: you can also use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox to check if JavaScript reads data from other url (tab Network->XHR) , and then you can try to read data from this url.

Comment: btw: if you want to learn then try http://toscrape.com

Answer (score 0):

This is url: https://time5.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/cgi-bin/get_ts2?original=1573441468689
I think you find a wrong url,this is a javascript requests.

response data example：

```
1573441559614|1573441559373|1573441559373
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be your final code also i would recommend using import re instead of bs4 if its simple

```
import requests
page = requests.get("https://time5.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/cgi-bin/get_ts2?original=1573441468689")
print(page.text)
```